# install from source Rstudio Desktop on debian9, error cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, debian, rstudio

I try to install rstudio 1.1.456 on debian9 :

```
Linux pc1 4.9.0-8-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) i686 GNU/Linux
```

I download and extract the tarball, create a build repertory in it, cd in it and launch this command (as it was showed in the INSTALL file)

```
sudo cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
[sudo]
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/zorg/rstudio-1.1.456" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I looked for a CMakeLists.txt from the root path but not much results :

```
sudo find -name "CMakeLists.txt"
./usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FortranCInterface/CMakeLists.txt
./usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/CMakeLists.txt
./usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/IntelVSImplicitPath/CMakeLists.txt
```

Thx

Comment: Note that this isn't about `[r]`, tag removed; and it is barely about the tag `[rstudio]`, though that tag can arguably also be removed since this is either completely about how to build something with `cmake` or something that should be a bug report to RStudio ... and I believe it's the first, not the second.

Comment: Two comments: i) This is going to be hard.  We have an open 'intent to package' for RStudio within Debian, and it has been open a long time.  RStudio needs to use slightly newer or different libraries than what it is Debian.  This is _not_ going to be a simple `cmake; make; make install`.  ii)  The prepackaged binaries work well and get updated.  I have been telling the good friends at RStudio for almost a decade that they really need something `apt`-getable and some work is being done on that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be in the directory you think you are in.  The files that your find is finding are not in the source download I retrieved.  I also suspect your unzipped source is a level down from where you are trying to run the cmake.

In a shell window run the following commands

```
cd /home/zorg/rstudio-1.1.456
ls -l
```

If you do not see CMakeLists.txt in the directory, but do have a subdirectory named rstudio-master, then run

```
cd rstudio-master
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Note you do not need to use sudo for the cmake command only for the make install.